# Konjunktiv II: Frage zu Wünschen

Tags: subjunctive

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen?

> Er wäre gerne entspannter sein.
>
> Er würde gerne entspannter sein.

Comment: Sorry, ich habe sie falsch geschrieben. Nicht es, sondern er!

Answer (score 2):

> Er sagt, er **wäre** gerne entspannter <s>sein</s>.
>
> Er sagt, er **würde** gerne entspannter **sein**.

This is both *Konjunktiv II*. As the *Konjunktiv II* form of *sein* is unique, this *würde-* replacement isn't used too often. The additional *sein* you used in the first sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: Note for who is wondering about this: "ungrammatical" is an educated word for "wrong". :-)

Comment: It's wrong because of wrong grammar. Not wrong syntax or style.

Comment: Danke für Erklärungen, aber sie haben keinen Unterschied wissen lassen. Gibt es großen Unterschied zwischen den Sätze oder nicht?

Comment: Es gibt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.